# Field extensions for polynomial $T^3+2T +1$ in $\mathbb F_3$

Tags: finite-fields, extension-field

I have the following polynomial over $\mathbb F_3$:
$$ f(T) = T^3+2T+1 $$
I would like to find out a field extension in order to add the roots of this polynomial.

**Edit**: by defining $\alpha\not\in \mathbb F_3$ such that $\alpha^3 + 2 \alpha + 1$ = 0, if I have another polynomial
$$ g(T) = T^3 + T^2+ T + 2 $$
I would like to find out if $$\mathbb F_3(\alpha)\cong \mathbb F_3(\beta)$$
being $\beta\not\in \mathbb F_3$ such that $\beta^3+\beta^2+\beta + 2$.

**Edit II**: I think they are not isomorphic, since in that case, if $\phi : \mathbb F_3(\alpha)\to \mathbb F_3(\beta)$ is an isomorphism, $\phi(\alpha) = \beta$, and
$$ 0 = \phi(0) = \phi(\alpha^3+2\alpha +1) = \beta^3 + 2\beta + 1 \quad\&\quad \beta^3 + \beta^2 + \beta + 2 = 0 $$
so $$ \beta^2 -\beta +1  =0= \beta^3+2\beta + 1 \implies \beta^3 = \beta^2$$
which is absurd.

Comment: What do you mean, "find a field extension"? You can always just take the splitting field, i.e., the smallest field in which the polynomial factors completely. Would you like to describe the splitting field in some particular way?

Comment: $f$ is irreducible since it is cubic and has no zeros in $\mathbb{F}_3.$ So one can adjoin a root $\theta$ of it, and use $\theta^3=-2\theta-1$ to reduce degrees when multiplying.

Comment: f(a) = 1 over $\mathbb F_3$ thus f has no linear factor hence no quadratic factor and it is irreducible. If you want just to add the roots the sum is obviously zero (Vieta formulae)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The polynomial $f(T)=T^3+2T+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_3$ because it has no roots (and has degree $3$). We can always build an extension field where $f$ has a root, namely
$$
K=\mathbb{F}_3[T]/(f(T))=\mathbb{F}_3[\alpha]
$$
where $\alpha^3+2\alpha+2=0$. Such a field $\mathbb{F}_3[\alpha]$ has dimension $3$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_3$, so it has $27$ elements.

Note that $\mathbb{F}_3[\alpha]$ can also be described as a splitting field of the polynomial $T^{27}-T$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$, by general theory of finite fields.

The polynomial $g(T)=T^3+T^2+T+2$ is irreducible as well. Hence the field $\mathbb{F}_3[\beta]$, where $\beta^3+\beta^2+\beta+2=0$ has $27$ elements as well. Hence it is a splitting field of $T^{27}-T$ and therefore it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_3[\alpha]$.

Of course the isomorphism doesn't map $\alpha$ to $\beta$. In $\mathbb{F}_3[\alpha]$ there is certainly a root for $g$. The elements of $\mathbb{F}_3[\alpha]$ are of the form $x=a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2$. Expand
$$
x^3+x^2+x+2
$$
and determine $a,b,c\in\mathbb{F}_3$ such that the expression is $0$. Then you get an isomorphism by sending $x$ to $\beta$, $x^2$ to $\beta^2$ and extending by linearity.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical extension is $\mathbf F_3[T]/(T^3+2T+1)$, and you set $\,\alpha=\overline T$.

As $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbf F_3$ (else it would have a root in $\mathbf F_3$), it is a field.

Moreover it's the splitting field of $f$, since it contains the two other roots:
$$\frac{-\alpha\pm 1}2.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can define $\alpha$ to be a solution of $T^3+2T+1=0$.  So you give $\alpha$ the relation,
$$
\alpha^3+2\alpha+1=0
$$
Adjoin this root and you have a new field, with the above relation for $\alpha$.